# TypeError: UserManager.create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Tags: python, django, model

I don't want to have the username field in Django and removed it
but now when I want to create a superuser got an error for missing the username field!!

```
error: TypeError: UserManager.create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
```

My user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Comment: Did you migrate the database changes?

Comment: Could you please add the `UserManager` class to the question? Specifically the `create_superuser` portion.